# Windows authentication: User name not displayed on the Web page

Tags: c#, authentication, iis

I published an `ASP.NET Web Application 4.0` and moved it the server. When users log in to their machines using `Windows authentication` and then go to the Web app page in the browser, their user name should be displayed on the aspx page.

On the server, `Windows authentication` is set to true and anonymous access is disabled.

However, the user name is not displayed on the aspx page. "Welcome Not authenticated" is displayed instead. Did I miss anything? Any pointers are appreciated.

This code is in SiteMaster.cs:

```
public partial class SiteMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            divWelcome.InnerHtml = "Welcome " + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        }
        else
        {
            divWelcome.InnerHtml = "Welcome " + "Not authenticated";
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if this has to be modified in `Web.config`. I'm not using the Login functionality as anyone at work can access the page:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try changing it to

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

This should fix it..